React Query with Axios not Redirecting to Login Page on Logout: Works with Fetch but not Axios
So this is my App.jsx file that uses the useQuery hook from react query to fetch the user data from a defined backend endpoint. The idea is to check if the data returns from the endpoint (which won't happen if the user is logged out and therefore no jwt tokens would be available in the backend) and render the pages accordingly. The code is as follows :
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

import LoginPage from "./pages/auth/login/LoginPage"
import SignUpPage from "./pages/auth/signup/SignUpPage"
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage"
import Sidebar from "./components/common/Sidebar"
import RightPanel from "./components/common/RightPanel"
import NotificationPage from "./pages/notification/NotificationPage"
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/ProfilePage"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import axios from "axios"
import LoadingSpinner from "./components/common/LoadingSpinner"



function App() {

  const { data: authUser, isLoading } = useQuery({
    //querykey: unique name to query to refer to it later from any other page or component
    queryKey: ["authUser"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/auth/me");
        const data = res.data;
        if(data.error) return null
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error(data.error || "something went wrong")
        }
        console.log("authUser is here: ", data)
        return data
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
      }
    },
    retry: false
  })
  // console.log(authUser)

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
        <LoadingSpinner size="lg" />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex max-w-6xl mx-auto">
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={authUser ? <HomePage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={!authUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={!authUser ? <SignUpPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
        <Route path='/notifications' element={authUser ? <NotificationPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
        <Route path='/profile/:username' element={authUser ? <ProfilePage /> : <Navigate to="login" />} />
      </Routes>
      <RightPanel />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App


Here is a strange issue I am facing:
the page for logout uses the idea of invalidating the query once the logout listener is invoked and thus should automatically check if the data is still there and should return back to the login-signup page, as you can see from the Route logic in the App.jsx file. I have checked, and the backend works fine and sends the correct data upon hitting from axios, and the login page uses exactly the same logic and things work perfectly fine there.
However, in the logout listener, while the query is being invalidated and console does give an unauthorized error, the page does not automatically redirect to the login page, and I am having to manually refresh it every time. For obvious reasons, using useNavigate wont work here as it would redirect again to the homepage as long as the data is still there. Here is the component for logout :
import XSvg from "../svgs/X";

import { MdHomeFilled } from "react-icons/md";
import { IoNotifications } from "react-icons/io5";
import { FaUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BiLogOut } from "react-icons/bi";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const Sidebar = () => {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const { mutate: logout } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/logout")
                const data = res.data
                console.log(data.message)
                if (res.status !== 200) throw new Error(data.error)
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) {
                    throw new Error(error.response.data.message)
                } else {
                    throw new Error(error.message)
                }
            }
        },

        onSuccess: () => {
            //invalidate the authUser query
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["authUser"] })
            toast.success("Logged out successfully")
        },
        onError: () => {
            toast.error("logout failed ")
        },
    })

    const handleLogout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        logout()
    }

    return (
        //stuff to render in the component. One of them is the logout icon which has the handleLogout listener. 
    );
};
export default Sidebar;

One more thing I noticed is that if I use javascript fetch() instead of axios in the App.jsx, it works as expected, the page is automatically re-rendered and thus reverted back to the login page once logout is successful. Here is the code where I am using fetch() ,keeping every other component and page codes exactly they are:
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

import LoginPage from "./pages/auth/login/LoginPage"
import SignUpPage from "./pages/auth/signup/SignUpPage"
import HomePage from "./pages/home/HomePage"
import Sidebar from "./components/common/Sidebar"
import RightPanel from "./components/common/RightPanel"
import NotificationPage from "./pages/notification/NotificationPage"
import ProfilePage from "./pages/profile/ProfilePage"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import axios from "axios"
import LoadingSpinner from "./components/common/LoadingSpinner"



function App() {

const { data: authUser, isLoading } = useQuery({
    //querykey: unique name to query to refer to it later from any other page or component
        queryKey: ["authUser"],
        queryFn: async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch("/api/auth/me");
                const data = await res.json();
                if (data.error) return null;
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error(data.error || "Something went wrong");
                }
                console.log("authUser is here:", data);
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        },
        retry: false,
    });
  // console.log(authUser)

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
        <LoadingSpinner size="lg" />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex max-w-6xl mx-auto">
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={authUser ? <HomePage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={!authUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={!authUser ? <SignUpPage /> : <Navigate to="/" />} />
        <Route path='/notifications' element={authUser ? <NotificationPage /> : <Navigate to="/login" />} />
        <Route path='/profile/:username' element={authUser ? <ProfilePage /> : <Navigate to="login" />} />
      </Routes>
      <RightPanel />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App


while using fetch() here is definitely an option here as it works, in order to maintain consistency throughout my code, I would prefer using axios. Also, I need to know what's going wrong in the code as I might face this again. Would really appreciate if anyone helps out, thanks!
